# ipsec tunnel between Cisco IOS router and Perle IOLAN SCS 32

Tags: cisco, vpn, ipsec, cisco-ios-15

I cannot get a IPsec tunnel up and run between a Perle IOLAN SCS 32 with firmware 4.5 and Cisco ASR 1001 with IOS  XE 15.3 - it fails in phase 2 with invalid proposals

Has some out there a sample for getting this right - defining a useable IPsec transform-set which can be accepted by the IOLAN?

See - the IOLAN supports this IKE1 & 2 proposals:

```
IKE Phase 1 Proposals
The following IKE Phase 1 proposals are supported by the IOLAN VPN gateway:
Ciphers—3DES, AES
Hashes—MD5, SHA1
Diffie-Hellman Groups—2 (MODP1024), 5 (MODP1536), 14 (MODP2048), 15 (MODP3072), 16 (MODP4096), 17 (MODP6144), 18 (MODP8192)
ESP Phase 2 Proposals
The following ESP Phase 2 proposals are supported by the IOLAN VPN gateway:
Ciphers—3DES, AES
Authentication Algorithms—MD5, SHA1, SHA2

and the vpn tunnel must be in "tunnel mode" 
perfect forward secrecy: no
protocol: ESP
mode: tunnel (not transport)
opportunistic encryption: no
aggressive mode: no
```

I have a ASR 1001 with a dedicated fvrf and ivrf for the clients - it comes in to a shared internet vrf and is put into a separate vrf (dmz_iolan)

The ike pase 1 seems to be negotiated correct but the ike phase 2 doesn't - here is the cryptomap:

```
crypto map IPSECMAP2 3003 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer 195.41.107.40
 set transform-set IOLAN-STD 
 set reverse-route distance 100
 set isakmp-profile IOLAN-PROF
 match address iolan01-acl
 reverse-route static
!

crypto isakmp profile IOLAN-PROF
   vrf DMZ_SCS
   keyring IPSEC-KEY2
   match identity address 195.41.107.40 255.255.255.255 INTERNET2
```

and my current IPsec proposals

```
crypto ipsec transform-set IOLAN-STD esp-3des 
 mode tunnel
!
```

and a bit of debug

```
ec 15 14:11:48.907: ISAKMP (45255): received packet from 195.41.107.40 dport 500 sport 500 INTERNET2 (R) QM_IDLE
Dec 15 14:11:48.907: ISAKMP: set new node 2045930127 to QM_IDLE
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255): processing HASH payload. message ID = 2045930127
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255): processing SA payload. message ID = 2045930127
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):Checking IPSec proposal 0
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP: transform 0, ESP_AES
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      encaps is 1 (Tunnel)
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (basic) of 28800
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-SHA
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):atts are acceptable.
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):Checking IPSec proposal 0
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP: transform 1, ESP_AES
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      encaps is 1 (Tunnel)
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (basic) of 28800
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-MD5
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):atts are acceptable.
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):Checking IPSec proposal 0
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP: transform 2, ESP_3DES
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      encaps is 1 (Tunnel)
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (basic) of 28800
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-SHA
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):atts are acceptable.
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):Checking IPSec proposal 0
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP: transform 3, ESP_3DES
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      encaps is 1 (Tunnel)
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (basic) of 28800
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-MD5
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255):atts are acceptable.
Dec 15 14:11:48.908: ISAKMP:(45255): IPSec policy invalidated proposal with error 256
Dec 15 14:11:48.910: ISAKMP:(45255): IPSec policy invalidated proposal with error 256
Dec 15 14:11:48.912: IPSEC(ipsec_process_proposal): transform proposal not supported for identity:
```

Comment: Please provide more info about the problem (current config, what have you tired, etc.)

Comment: hi again sorry for the delay - been busy elsewhere - see the iolan supports this:

Comment: I have tried to put a bit details on but do you have a proposal for a setup like this:

Comment: IKE Phase 1 Proposals
The following IKE Phase 1 proposals are supported by the IOLAN VPN gateway:
Ciphers—3DES, AES
Hashes—MD5, SHA1
Diffie-Hellman Groups—2 (MODP1024), 5 (MODP1536), 14 (MODP2048), 15 (MODP3072), 16 (MODP4096), 17 (MODP6144), 18 (MODP8192)
ESP Phase 2 Proposals
The following ESP Phase 2 proposals are supported by the IOLAN VPN gateway:
Ciphers—3DES, AES
Authentication Algorithms—MD5, SHA1, SHA2

Comment: here a little more debug:

Comment: I can see that the IOLAN uses OpenSwan VPN 2.4

Comment: ok - have got the right combinations:crypto isakmp policy 25
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 5
 lifetime 3600

Comment: and IPsec proposals: crypto ipsec transform-set IOLAN-STD esp-3des esp-md5-hmac

Comment: After few hours spent on this I just put DH to no-pfs and it works!